# How do I enchant un-enchantable items?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

I recently came across the map which had an enchanted Blaze Rod and Book. I've searched the forums, and nothing seems to clarify this. How can one enchant an un-enchantable item, e.g. Blaze Rod, Cyan Dye, Paper, etc. Is there a way to do this without mods?

Comment: What specific enchantments did they have, or were they just glowing like an enchanted item?

Comment: SPC might help... I've used it to get enchantments higher than the theoretical highest (I've used tools with Fortune X before (don't do this: If you hit gravel with it, you will crash your game)). I've never tried enchanting unenchantable items... (time for science!)

Comment: The blaze rod had the one with fire (sets things on fire), and the book had knockback and smite

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons)

Comment: @pppery This question predates that other question by more than 2 years. This question already has a large number of upvotes and has multiple highly upvoted answers. Shouldn't the dupe closure be the other way around?

Comment: I'm very reluctant to unseat long-established canonical questions just because an older question asking the same thing (especially one covering a specific corner-case not shared by most duplicates) happened to be found. (And I note that the pre-existing canonical has twice as many views and also has multiple highly-upvoted answers)

Comment: @pppery This older question doesn't seem to be a duplicate of that newer one. This one's more specific. Related meta post: [Is a question a duplicate just because it asks for something that can be part of another question's answer?](//meta.arqade.com/q/7359/4797) Also, the meta post, [On ending Chronological Oppression…](//meta.arqade.com/a/8188/4797) states that an earlier question can only be closed as a dupe of a newer one if the new question (and/or its answers) is *objectively better* than the earlier question. I don't think that's the case here.

Comment: While the OP does not *specifically* say they want to use commands in this question, commands really are the only feasible option to get the job done. I would agree that the other question has the best up-to-date answer and the best question body, so I agree with the close votes on this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can enchant an item that is normally not enchantable with a couple of methods. One way is to use an anvil and an enchanted book in creative mode. In creative mode, the game ignores the normal rules of what can and cannot be enchanted.

You can also do it using commands with NBT data embedded within it. The format for the `/give` command is as follows:

```
/give [player] [item] [quantity] [data value] [NBT tags]
```

For this, we're interested in the [NBT tags] part. The format for the enchantment tag is `{ench:[{id:x1,lvl:y1},{id:x2,lvl:y2},...]}`. So the full command for just giving a player an enchanted item would be as follows:

```
/give [player] [item] [quantity] [data value (normally 0)] {ench:[{id:x1,lvl:y1},{id:x2,lvl:y2},...]}
```

Check out [this post](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1969520-17-using-summon-give-datatags-in-map-making-tutorials/) on the Minecraft Forums for more details about using NBT data in commands.

For example, if I wanted to give myself (or the player) a stick with Sharpness V and Silk Touch I, I'd use the following command:

```
/give @p stick 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:33,lvl:1}]}
```

You can do this for any item, any enchantment, and any value of level.

Also, a note: using the `/enchant` command does **not** work. The `/enchant` command respects all normal enchantment rules, regardless of the gamemode of the player. Even though you can make an Efficiency V stick with an anvil in creative mode, you cannot do it using the `/enchant` command.

Answer (score 5):

I addition to James' answer, you may also want to look at those two videos that explain the process:

and

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the videos here.

Comment: if you are in creative you can enhant EVERYTHING with an anvil and enchanted books :D

Answer (score 4):

To enchant enter this command

```
/enchant add [enchantmant] [Level]
```

Example:

```
/enchant add fire_aspect 10
```

That command will enchant the item that you are holding to set mobs on fire

Comment: It won't work unless it's an item you would regularly be able to enchant. You can only put Fire Aspect on swords with the `/enchant` command.

Answer (score 2):

They are generally using editing tools, like MCEdit, to create the worlds and add into them the items that you are mentioning. Like the Super Hostile maps that you can get (I believe its Enchanted Caves that has a collection of ever more powerfully enchanted signs that are really very handy weapons in that map :))

I have yet, however, to see a command in SPC that would allow you to put an enchantment on an non-enchantable item. I am sure someone will correct me if I am wrong on this aspect :))

Comment: So can you add enchanted non-enchantable items into the world via MCEDit?

Comment: There are quite a few editing tools that will allow you to achieve this. MCEdit is one of the more popular world editors. The videos posted by @rexp use Single Player Commands (a Minecraft mod) in order to do it it seems. Minecraft is a very very modifiable sandbox :)

Answer (score 1):

It was most likely tims the enchanter (a plugin) which makes it possible to enchant anything like the blaze rod and book. with it you can enchant a sword with all enchantments in-game like protection to level 127 etc. (127 is the highest level).

Answer (score 0):

With the new Enchanted books in snapshot 12w49a made it possible to enchant anything. Just go into creative mode, take an enchanted book (Or enchant a book to get it), place it in an anvil together with the item and bam!

Answer (score 0):

Combine it with an enchanted book with an anvil.

Comment: This is incorrect. You cannot enchant a Paper item in this way.

Comment: In creative you can.

Answer (score 0):

On a previous version of Old Minecraft (Xbox edition, might only be the 360) you could enchant anything with anything! Feathers with feather falling, tnt with looting, gold blocks with unbreaking! The list goes on. Sadly blocks that were enchanted did not shimmer when placed :(  Oh, and the devs fixed that in another update, much to my dismay (RIP Feather enchanted feather falling)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

NBTedit, singleplayercommands(e.g. /enchant add 21 4),MCedit

I have a tutorial on NBTedit here:

Comment: Can you add an explanation to this in case the video ever disappears.

Comment: Just like it did...