# Minecraft Bow Command ./give multiple enchants

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

So I have this one command creation that I want to use. And I am not sure about the syntax. I want to put multiple enchants on my bow. Can you guys  help me with my command so that it works?

Here is my command:

```
/.give @p minecraft:bow 1 0 {display:{Lore:[Forged by Dark_Matrix9]}, Unbreakable:1ench:[{id:48,lvl:10000,id:49,lvl:10000,id:50,lvl:10000,id:51,lvl:10000]}
```

How do I connect the enchants?

Answer (score 3):

You missed out a comma in your command. Also, you have a full-stop after you slash. You also missed out a curly brace. Also, you did not format the enchantments correctly. Here's your command:

```
/give @p minecraft:bow 1 0 {display:{Lore:[Forged by Dark_Matrix9]}, Unbreakable:1, ench:[{id:48,lvl:10000}, {id:49, lvl:10000}, {id:50, lvl:10000}, {id:51, lvl:10000}]}
```

This is what you get:
[image]

Comment: See [this](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/191557/108497) for more info

Answer (score 0):

Here's the corrected code:
`/give @a minecraft:bow 1 0 {Unbreakable:1,ench:[{id:48,lvl:10000},{id:49,lvl:10000},{id:50,lvl:10000},{id:51,lvl:10000}],display:{Lore:["Forged by Dark_Matrix9"]}}`
[image]

Comment: How is this different from my answer, besides swapping the positions of the JSON tags?

Comment: Duplicate answers are frowned upon here, especially when they plagarise from other answers. This may be deleted.