# stacking up op enchantments on a sword?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know how to get a weapon with an enchanment higher than the limit. But can you stack up more of these enchantments on the same item?  For example, could you have Sharpness X and Looting X on one sword?

I've been using this command:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {ench[{id:16,lvl:10}]}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of  [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons) or [How do I create tools with multiple properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/349279/185203)

Answer (score 3):

Yes, add it as another compound tag in the `ench` list:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:10},{id:21,lvl:10}]}
```