# Can a player give an enchanted item on Xbox One?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I found all info for this question here: [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons?newreg=1fecb4f827974c94a4edc63a1178f677)

I get an error when typing The following:

```
/give @p diamond_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:17,lvl:2},{id:19,lvl:30}]}
```

The error:

> x Line 1, Column 2: Missing '}' or object member name

Can the "component:json" field be used on Xbox One or PC only?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Give](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/give_command.php) and [Enchant](https://www.digminecraft.com/game_commands/enchant_command.php) command are not available on Xbox One.

I believe this is the case for all commands - the console editions do not support commands just yet.

**EDIT:** It appears that you are right that the problem with this command is that the console editions (or "Bedrock Edition") do not support that particular command (emphasis mine):

> *components: json (optional)*<sup>[Bedrock Edition only]</sup> 
>   Like DataTags **but only supports `CanPlaceOn` and `CanDestroy` functions** (for example, `/give @p iron_shovel 1 0 {"minecraft:can_destroy":{"blocks":["grass"]}})`

Comment: They support the commands. Just not sure if I'm doing it correct or the JSON portion isn't supported. E.g. I can do /give @s diamond_sword 1 0 and i get a diamond sword.

Comment: I've also notice that the links you provided aren't up to date.

Comment: @TRyanWolf fair enough. As far as I can tell, your syntax is fine, but in truth the error message makes no sense, from my understanding of the Minecraft commands.

Answer (score 1):

For Id:19, lvl 999 is too high for an xbox.

I tried on my xbox one (update aquatic) to get sharpness 999 but said it must be a max of 5; 999 is not a valid lvl. It might work if you change it to a lower lvl.