# How can I /give myself something stronger than the maximum book enchantment level?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm new to commands but I made a few which are a bit complicated, in 1.12.2. But recently after the Aquatic update, I've been unable to use commands to give me items stronger than the enchantment book maximum level. I would like to make a command where I can get items with enchantments of 999. How can I do this?

I have a solution but it gets annoying: go on 1.12.2, use the command for items, turn Minecraft off, and reload it on 1.3.1. The item will be saved in my toolbar. But like I said, this is pretty annoying. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Can you please try to use proper spelling and grammar? I have no idea what you're trying to tell us.

Comment: He's saying that in 1.3.1 he can spawn items as good as x (whereas x is the maximum "Non-cheated" ammount). On previous versions he could spawn items better than x. He's asking how he can spawn items better than x in 1.3.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons)

Answer (score 4):

I think I have a solution to your problem as I had the same problem a few weeks ago. The format of the /give command changed quite a bit in 1.13. One now puts the tags next to the command instead of as a seperate argument.
For example, this is a command that gives you a diamond sword with sharpness 20:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:20}]} 1
```

You can put other enchantments in here by replacing "minecraft:sharpness" with something else and of course the lvl tag is just the level of the enchant. Multiple enchantments can be done like this:

```
/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:20},{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:10}]} 1
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to get a command block in Minecraft.

```
/give yourname minecraft:command_block 1
```

then put the command block on the ground press right click on it and paste this command:

```
give @p minecraft:diamond_pickaxe 1 0 {ench:[{id:"fortune",lvl:999}]}
```

that's it. for example i want to get a diamond_axe to have an fortune 200.
so i'll be using this command:

```
give @p minecraft:diamond_axe 1 0 {ench:[{id:"fortune",lvl:200}]}
```

Answer (score 0):

In a command block, type:

```
/give @s netherite_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:"sharpness",lvl:2147483647}]}
```

And if you want more than only one enchantment, type:

```
/give @s netherite_sword 1 0 {ench:[{id:"sharpness",lvl:2147483647},{id:"knockback",lvl:2147483647}]}
```

and you can keep on going on with all the enchantments you want by putting a comma after every curly bracket, and typing in another enchantment-thing.If you do it with literally any item, dirt, even, the item will get all the enchantments.
PS. If you go into spectator mode and occupy a mob, and give yourself an item, the mob will get the item, and you won't.

Really, Minecraft is a great game.

Answer (score -1):

It’s better to enchant a sword with sharpness 100000000 so that the ender dragon doesn’t even have stand a chance. The best sword would have:

- Sharpness 1000000000
- Sweeping Edge 10
- Bane of Arthropods 10000
- Fire Aspect 2
- Knockback 5

Obviously the update has changed everything, but the command would be:

```
/give @p minecraft:netherite_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:1000000000},{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:5},{id:"minecraft:Sweeping Edge",lvl:10,{id:"minecraft:Bane of Arthropods",lvl:10000,{id:"minecraft:Fire aspect",lvl:2,{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:5] 1
```

Comment: SORRY, WHAT?! Can you please just write in standard capitalization? Also, what is this a reaction to?

Comment: 32767 is the max of a short, these numbers wouldn’t work

Comment: Is there a way to make the 1000000000 not show up as a clickable phone number or is that just an iOS thing?