# "ench" NBT tag doesn't work in Minecraft 1.13

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to get a bow with a top-level Power enchantment. A command similar to this worked before:

```
/give @p minecraft:bow{ench:[{id:48,lvl:32767}]}
```

...But not in 1.13. Changing the ID to `power` didn't work either:

```
/give @p minecraft:bow{ench:[{id:power,lvl:32767}]}
```

It just gave an ordinary, unenchanted bow. Quotes didn't change anything either:

```
/give @p minecraft:bow{ench:[{id:"power",lvl:32767}]}
```

I don't know what to do with the command format being changed in 1.13. Does anyone know how to fix the `ench` NBT tag?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons)

Comment: The 1.13 change is specifically addressed by the answer https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/372269/148546

Answer (score 4):

According to [the wiki](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#Item_data), you'll want to use the NBT tag `Enchantments` instead of `ench`. (You'll also want to change the ID, e.g. to `power` like you did, according to [this chart](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Enchanting#IDs).) So, while I haven't tested it, this command should work:

```
/give @p minecraft:bow{Enchantments:[{id:power,lvl:32767}]}
```

(You may need to specify it as `id:"minecraft:power"`, but I don't think this is necessary.)