# How can I enchant leather armor with a command block in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I'm trying to enchant leather armor using a command block. I want it to be **red**, with **protection 1**, and **unbreakable**. I did research for like an hour and I can't find anything about it, and hope anyone can help.
Thanks.

Comment: What version and platform are you using?

Comment: What did you find on your research? What search terms should you enter? It should take considerably less than an hour, closer to a minute, to find the right wiki pages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons)

Answer (score 1):

You can use 1.12 online command generators for this, one can be found on [minecraftcommand.science](https://minecraftcommand.science/armor-generator). Here you can generate a command for any color and enchantments for your armor, and "convert" it to a newer format manually.

The command for red leather armor with `Protection I` and `Unbreakable` will look like this:

```
/give @p leather_helmet 1 0 {display:{color:16711680},ench:[{id:0,lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1}
```

The command for 1.13 and 1.14 looks like this:

```
/give @p leather_helmet{display:{color:16711680},Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:1}],Unbreakable:1}
```

What you need to do is move everything that's in brackets directly to the item ID, and remove the count and damage. After that, instead of `ench` type `Enchantments`, and replace the number ID of the enchantment with the name ID.

Of course, you can replace `leather_helment` by any other leather armor part.

Comment: I can't found anything for doing it in 1.13 that's the point :/

Comment: @Sjimoon Sorry! I edited the post and showed how to convert the command to 1.13+.

Answer (score 0):

**/give @a leather_chestplate{display:{color:11546150},Enchantments:[{id:protection,lvl:1},{id:unbreaking,lvl:3}]} 1**

This is the exact command (for Minecraft 1.14) that you need to enter to get a red leather tunic, with protection 1. I personally do not know how to make it unbreakable, so I replaced it with Unbreaking 3. Is that okay?

You can replace `@a` with `@p`or `{Insert Player's Name Here}`

You can also replace `leather_chestplate` with `leather_leggings`, `leather_ boots` or `leather_helmet`

Hope I helped...