# How to give items in minecraft java 1.16.2 that have enchantments

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm trying to make a Minecraft java map and I'm confused about how to give enchanted items, and because I need multiple at a time, I can't use /enchant. I have no idea about how to go about this as after I input the amount it doesn't let me input anything else.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in 1.16.2:

```
/give @p minecraft:item{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:enchant_1",lvl:num},{id:"minecraft:enchant_2",lvl:num}]} 1
```

Replace the `enchant_x` with the desired enchantment(s) and `num` with the desired level. If you want to have more than this, just add this string of code within the square brackets. `{id:"minecraft:enchant_name",lvl:num}` Make sure you add commas between each enchant block. I hope this helps.