# How do I test for items with nbt in 1.16.4 using execute command

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to execute

```
/execute if entity @p[nbt={Inventory:[{id:"minecraft:diamond"}]}] run enchant @a minecraft:unbreaking 3
```

except only if the diamond has infinity on it
ok
I use Minecraft Java 1.16.4 and optifine

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory) and [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/191554/185203)

Comment: no it isnt a duplicate what i want is:
1: Player Has Diamond [minecraft:diamond] with infinity level 1 on it [id:infinity,lvl:1]
2. if player has diamond with infinity on it run the command referenced in #3
3. [/enchant @s Unbreaking 3]

Comment: @78ThousandNumbers We linked those questions because they answer your question *together*. The first one shows you where item data goes, and the second one shows you what the enchantment data looks like. We'd like you to go to the two questions and see if you can put them together to find the answer to your question.