# How do I get sharpness 1000 on a diamond sword or netherite sword on minecraft java edition?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

How do I get a sword with sharp 1000 on Java Edition? My friend is on Bedrock and he has a sharp 100 sword. I tried it but didn't work. I wanted to know how to get it to work on 1.16.5. The tutorial is on 1.12.2 so how do I do it with commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons)

Answer (score 4):

`/give @p minecraft:diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness", lvl:1000}]} 1`

is usually the command to give a item/object a enchantment with a crazy high level.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [MCstacker](https://mcstacker.net) to generate commands, specifically the give command with NBT enchantment data.