# Why is the /enchant command giving me an error when I go outside the normal level bounds?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

When I tried to use the `/enchant` command on an item to get sharpness 6, it wouldn't work and gave me an error. Is there a way to toggle safe enchants? Or is there a different way to approach this?

Comment: What is the command you're trying to use to get high-level enchantments? Perhaps it's not restricted but you're just doing it wrong. Also, I've removed your extra questions from your post. Please keep your question posts to one question only.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/191554/185203)

Comment: nope, not that. It's the extra levels.

Comment: See [How do I make stacks of unstackable items?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/382652/185203) for the second question that was edited out of this post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `/enchant` command doesn't support out of bounds enchantments. Try using `/give` instead:

```
/give @p diamond_axe{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:19s},{id:"minecraft:fire_aspect",lvl:45s}]}
```

Comment: You really shouldn't answer a question by copy-pasting my answer to a different question -- close vote the question as duplicate instead.

Comment: @ppery but the question isn't the same, i credited you anyway

Comment: @ppery I've changed it so its original now

Comment: You've misunderstood my point entirely. The point I was trying to make is that the fact that you can validly answer a question my copying an answer from a different question nearly verbatim means that the questions are in fact duplicates.

Comment: @pppery that's how meta sites work. But on the main site you don't close as duplicates unless the **question** is the same, not the *answer*

Comment: I think it's commonly known here that you shouldn't answer duplicates, am I wrong?

Comment: I'm sorry I was legitimately asking

Comment: @RayWu "I think it's commonly known here" how is that a question? bruh. If u were actually asking then im sorry but it doesnt really sound like it

Answer (score -1):

If you want to enchant an item with very high enchantments that are not supposed to be allowed, like sharpness 6, you'd need to use /give. For example, for a sword with sharpness 12 and knockback 5, you'd need to use:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:12},{id:knockback,lvl:5}]}.
```

You can enchant just about everything, so if you want a stick that has a very high knockback, you can simply use:

```
/give @p stick{Enchantments:[{id:knockback,lvl:30}]}
```

You can replace these enchantments with any enchantments, for example, you can use:

```
/give @p diamond_sword{Enchantments:[{id:smite,lvl:65},{id:looting,lvl:10000},{id:fire_aspect,lvl:12}]}
```

or:

```
/give @p stick{Enchantments:[{id:sharpness,lvl:130}]}
```

If you want to get an enchanted pickaxe, you can use:

```
/give @p diamond_pickaxe{Enchantments:[{id:fortune,lvl:1000},{id:efficiency,lvl:10000}]}
```

You can do this with any enchantments you want, and almost any object you want.