# Is there a way to enchant an item with /give

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I'm making a Minecraft map where you have to kill bees and I'm trying to make the command block give you a sweeping edge sword and I just can't figure it out.

Comment: This is pretty easy to search online. Have you tried looking for answers online?

Comment: No, not really.

Comment: I figured it out

Comment: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons This question is the same as this one.

Comment: I posted that as an answer, not a comment