# How do I give myself a Netherite pickaxe on Minecraft with high enchantment levels on the 1.17 snapshots?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I know I have to use the `/give` command, but what do I put after the `netherite_pickaxe` part? I am using the new 1.17 snapshots.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons)

Comment: to give you a headstart, you basically use something like `/give @p netherite_pickaxe{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:unbreakability",lvl:2s},{id:"minecraft:power",lvl:30s}]}` I'm not sure if that's the totally correct command though.

Answer (score -1):

`/give @p <id>{Enchantments:[{id:<id>,lvl:<lvl>}]} 1` replacing things in <> with the appropriate text.

Comment: This is less useful that the answers to the duplicate suggestion. You shouldn't answer duplicate questions by providing even less specific information than the answers to their duplicate.