# How do I enchant a stick with Knockback 3?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Can someone tell me how to create a knockback three stick? I searched this up everywhere on Google, but could not find any proper answers. By the way, this is for Java Edition.

Comment: What sites did you try that did not work?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/191554/how-do-i-give-players-already-enchanted-tools-armour-weapons)

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use the give command for this.
The following command would give a knockback 3 stick.

```
/give @p stick{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:3s}]} 1
```

For more enchantments, a command like this can be used. This command would give a knockback 3, sharpness 3 stick.

```
/give @p stick{Enchantments:[{id:"minecraft:sharpness",lvl:3s},{id:"minecraft:knockback",lvl:3s}]} 1
```