# How to summon a mob with an enchanted item?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I don't know how to summon a entity with an enchanted item, please help!
(version 1.12.2)

command:

```
summon minecraft:zombie ~ ~ ~ {HandItems:[{id:iron_axe,Count:1}]}
```

How can I make the iron axe enchanted?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where do I put item tags on items inside a chest or your inventory?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/272179/where-do-i-put-item-tags-on-items-inside-a-chest-or-your-inventory) or [How do I give players already enchanted Tools/Armour/Weapons](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/191554/185203)

Comment: Or you could enchant the weapon manually, throw into the ground and use `data get` to see how it looks

Answer (score 0):

Here is a example of what to do,

Zombie holding Wooden Sword with Sharpness I and Frost Walker II

```
/summon Zombie ~ ~0.5 ~ {NoAI:true,Attributes:[{Base:0.0d,Name:"generic.maxHealth"}],HandItems:[{},{id:"minecraft:wooden_sword",tag:{ench:[{id:16s,lvl:1s},{id:9s,lvl:2s}]}}
```

Where it says `id:"minecraft:(you can put any item here)`

For enchantments here is a list of ids,

**For Armours:**

0   Protection
1   Fire Protection
2   Feather Falling
3   Blast Protection
4   Projectile Protection
5   Respiration
6   Aqua Affinity
7   Thorns
8   Depth Strider

**For Weapons:**

16   Sharpness
17  Smite
18   Bane Of Arthropods
19   Knockback
20   Fire Aspect
21   Looting

**For Tools:**

32   Efficiency
33   Silk Touch
34   Unbreaking
35   Fortune

**For Bows:**

48   Power
49   Punch
50   Flame
51   Infinity

**For Fishing Rods:**

61   Luck of the Sea
62   Lure