# Enchanting non-enchantable items on MCPE 1.2.3 iOS

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know that there is the /enchant command, but it, as usual, only does armor and weapons and fishing rods, and my long-waited "Sticky the Stick" is unmakeable. Any suggestions on how to enchant any item without a special app? Commands only, please.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like "non-enchantable" items cannot **normally** be crafted.

These bug reports denounce it.

[Bug MCPE 15500](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-15500?jql=text%20~%20%22enchant%20stick%22)

[Bug MCPE 11993](https://bugs.mojang.com/browse/MCPE-11993?jql=text%20~%20%22enchant%20stick%22)

However, using **commands or creative mode**, it is possible to do. [Check out this link to another Arqade question.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57717/how-do-i-enchant-un-enchantable-items)

From what I have seen, it is possible to use an anvil and enchanted book in creative mode. You will also be able to name your stick "Sticky the Stick".

You could also use the `/give` command to get an enchanted stick. [Check out the Arqade question link earlier in this post for more information about this topic.](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57717/how-do-i-enchant-un-enchantable-items)

Note that `/enchant` will not work. This command only enchants "enchantable" items.

**Update:** I did not see the part about commands only. Sorry about that. I would recommend using an anvil and enchanted book in creative mode though since I know you can name it "Sticky the Stick".

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't, since the command makes sure to check if the enchantment is compatible with said item. So, if you have a sword, you couldn't give it protection, an armour enchantment. So, in turn, there aren't any enchantments made for basic items like food or sticks, leaving them without the ability to be enchanted.

Comment: Adding on to The Mattbat999, the `/enchant` command is restricted by what you can enchant in survival (or MCPE) on an anvil. On the Java Edition (PC or computer), you can enchant anything with an anvil if you're on creative or use the `/give` command. Related: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57717/how-do-i-enchant-un-enchantable-items