# Enchanting random items in Bedrock Edition

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

[There's a cool thing in Minecraft Java that lets players to enchant items that normally aren't enchantable](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57717/how-do-i-enchant-un-enchantable-items) and I've been wanting a way to enchant unenchantable items in Bedrock without some client.

Using the accepted answer from the linked question, I went to try this command and modify it because they are different:

```
/give @p stick 1 0 {ench:[{id:16,lvl:5},{id:33,lvl:1}]}
```

However, I want a Knockback V stick instead. After some failures, I have a special draft:

```
/give @s stick 1 0 {}
```

I'm not sure what the keywords are in the components section, so I will need help in that one.

How can I get a Knockback V stick using commands?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I use an NBT editor to modify item properties?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/376577/how-do-i-use-an-nbt-editor-to-modify-item-properties)

Comment: So I chose "Yes" for both even if I still don't have an NBT editor, but I now have some clues for a Knockback X stick.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe Do you understand those posts we linked you to from here? If you have any questions, please feel free to ask in the comments of those posts.

Comment: @ExpertCoder14 I don't think it would work in favor of the "Roomba", mainly because since this is unanswered and not voted positively, it could get deleted, and I might not have enough stuff to talk about. Sorry, but I might ask a follow-up question instead.